# Enable tab-complete in RubyMine Navigation File and Class Search?

Tags: intellij-idea, rubymine

In RubyMine, when you use the cmd+shift+o search and start typing in directories, it will find the directory; but you have to finish typing the directory name followed by the file you want. What I would like to have is (similar to terminal), I can hit tab when it recognizes I'm typing a directory and it will complete the directory name and allow me to keep typing. Is there a configuration option for this? The current behavior has the tab key do the same thing as the return key.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to finish typing the directory name. You can type any part of the directory name, followed by a slash, and then type the file name, and RubyMine will show all files that match the specified parts of the file name and directory name.